# tcpdump - setting cmdline from the variable

Tags: bash, variables, tcpdump, packet-sniffers

Does anyone have an idea on how to properly enclose following expression into the variable and use it as a tcpdump cmdline?

```
filter="-i eth0 tcp[13] & 8 == 8"
```

and use it like this:

```
`tcpdump $filter`
```

The problem is that shell expands this expression differently depending on how ", ', \ are used, but no matter what, parameters are still not properly passed to execve() and basically tcpdump returns an error each time it's run. any ideas? Below is how I tested it:

```
root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# filter="-i eth0 tcp[13] & 8 == 8"
root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# echo "$filter"
-i eth0 tcp[13] & 8 == 8
root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# filter="-i eth0 tcp[13] & 8 == 8"
root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# echo $filter
-i eth0 & 8 == 8 
root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# strace tcpdump "$filter" |& grep -iE '^execve'
execve("/usr/sbin/tcpdump", ["tcpdump", "-i eth0 tcp[13] & 8 == 8"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0  #doesn't work, everything passed as a single argument
root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# strace tcpdump $filter |& grep -iE '^execve'
execve("/usr/sbin/tcpdump", ["tcpdump", "-i", "eth0", "&", "8", "==", "8"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0 #missing tcp flags and each part of string delimited with space is treated as a separate argument

root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# filter="-i eth0 tcp\[13\] \& 8 \=\= 8"
root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# echo $filter
-i eth0 tcp\[13\] \& 8 \=\= 8
 root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# strace tcpdump $filter |& grep -iE '^execve'
execve("/usr/sbin/tcpdump", ["tcpdump", "-i", "eth0", "tcp\\[13\\]", "\\&", "8", "\\=\\=", "8"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0 #tcpdump escapes our escapes?!
root@mikePL:~/myConfig/scripts# strace tcpdump -i eth0 'tcp[13] & 8 == 8' |& grep -iE '^execve' 
execve("/usr/sbin/tcpdump", ["tcpdump", "-i", "eth0", "tcp[13] & 8 == 8"],    [/* 16 vars */]) = 0 # this is how it should look like
```

Currently I am writing an CLI interface for the tcpdump, I thought that everything was covered but then I realized that the berkeley filters were e.g. '[]' have to be used do not work due to the above issue.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Escape the \&, that should help.  You may have to escape the == too, not sure.

Comment: @ErickGriffin I did that, I escaped all special characters but when '\' is added to the cmdline it's escaped by the tcpdump itself and it still does not work

Comment: add another one, \\&

Comment: It could also be the bash pre-processor taking a shot at your command line before strace get's it, so you could try putting single-quotes around that variable, that would tell the shell to don't process it.

Comment: Here's an example of how I do essentially the same thing in one of my scripts:   STATUS=\`$SUDO status $SECUREGATEWAYMAIN | $AWK '$0 ~ /securegateway/ && /running/ { print "OK"};'\`   Don't mind the uppercase, all commands are figured out per plaform, so where you see $SUDO = sudo, etc...

Comment: @ErickGriffin using single quotes will use literally the name of the variable passing '$filter' as an argument to the exec. adding double escapes also does not work. quite funny thing happened when I tried to escape ' enclosed within the variable like so: filter="-i eth0 \'tcp[13] & 8 == 8\'" That's what strace got: execve("/usr/sbin/tcpdump", ["tcpdump", "-i eth0 \\\'tcp[13] & 8 == 8\\\'"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0. No idea where those additional '\' came from.

Comment: oh, '\' and ' where additionally escaped by the tcpdump, got it